# yum history list + how to verify rpm historical status

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum, rpm

The rpm command gives every package installed a transaction ID. The transaction ID is a Unix time stamp (number of seconds since January 1, 1970). You can then perform some operations on packages based on the transaction ID.

but on our rhel machines when we try to get info from  `yum history list $rpm_name`

then we get the following errors

```
Bad transaction IDs, or package(s), given
Error: Failed history list
```

usually if rpm was removed the we should get from `yum history list $rpm_name`

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    29 | root <root>              | 2020-11-24 00:54 | Erase          |   26
     1 | System <unset>           | 2019-12-15 14:05 | Install        | 1363
history list
```

and if rpm is installed then we should get from `yum history list $rpm_name`

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    31 | root <root>              | 2020-11-26 01:06 | Install        |    1
```

but what is the meaning of the errors below ? that we get from `yum history list $rpm_name`

*note - rpm_name - is rpm name*

```
Bad transaction IDs, or package(s), given
Error: Failed history list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the name of the package, not the name of a file.

So you would use `libcgroup`, not `libcgroup-0.41-19.el7.x86_64.rpm`.